# Excel Add-in goes blank after sync()

Tags: angularjs, excel, office-js

I have created an Excel add-in using an AngularJS app and I am getting very odd behavior.

After a period of inactivity (~2-3 minutes), when the user performs an action that requires a `sync()` the add-in disappears (goes blank) but *no exception is thrown*.

The code is structured as following (just an example):

AngularJS controller calls:

```js
$scope.hearbeat = function () {
  excelService.heartbeat(EXCEL_RESOURCES.WorkSheetName, EXCEL_RESOURCES.TableName);
};
```

The Excel service is an AngularJS service that makes use of `Excel.Run`:

```js
this.heartbeat = function (worksheetName, tableName) {
    console.log('heartbeat');

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        // Create Proxy for the current opened worksheet
        var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(worksheetName);
        sheet.tables.load("name");

        var table = sheet.tables.getItem(tableName);
        var tableRows = null;
        return ctx.sync()
            .then(function () {
                tableRows = table.rows;
                tableRows.add();
            })
            .then(ctx.sync)
            .then(function () {
                table = sheet.tables.getItem(tableName);
            })
            .then(ctx.sync)
            .then(function () {
                var lastRow = table.getRange().getLastRow();
                lastRow.delete();
            })
            .then(ctx.sync);
    }).then(function () {
        deferred.resolve(true);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        var error = excelService.convertError(err);
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

This only happens when using the add-in within Excel Online and it is really strange that no exception is even thrown.

Is there a way to re-initialize the Office.js integration?

Comment: Can you capture fiddler trace and see what's going on? You should look for any 504 or 500 errors that may be impacting your add-in. Not sure if it is the code shown above or something outside of it is causing the issue.

Comment: BTW - you have more ctx.sync() that needed. You only need to sync when you need to refer to properties that you read. As long as you are queuing up operation such as add, delete, you can do it all in one batch (and execute one ctx.sync() at the end). Also, consider using getItemOrNullObject instead of getItem when you are unsure if the object exists or not.